# How to avoid discontinuities in a mesh

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I try to display a gyroid structure (triply periodic minimal surface) in python. I have tried several packages but pyvista seems the more appropriate for my study. The gyroid is a periodic minimal surface that can be modelled according to the following equation:

sin(a(i - 1))  * cos(a(j -  1)) + sin(a(j -  1))  * cos(a(k -  1)) + sin(a(k -  1)) * cos(a(i -  1)) < b

where a is a scaling parameter equal to 2pi/l and l is the unit cell length. The value b controls the volume fraction and typically varies between 1.32 and 0.15.
It seems to work well nevertheless from a certain value of b, discontinuities appear in my mesh which is not correct. I tried to use pymesh to repair it or scypy.interpolate but it changes nothing. Do you have an idea? Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

```
import pyvista as pv
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos, sin, pi
from random import uniform
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
import pymeshfix


lattice_par = 1.0  # Unit cell length

a = (2*pi)/lattice_par


def gyroid(x, y, z, b=1.2):
    return sin(a*(x - 1))*cos(a*(y - 1)) + sin(a*(y - 1))*cos(a*(z - 1)) + sin(a*(z - 1))*cos(a*(x - 1)) - b


# %% Data

x, y, z = np.mgrid[-2:2:31j, -3:3:31j, 0:4:31j]

vol = gyroid(x, y, z)

grid = pv.StructuredGrid(x, y, z)

grid["vol"] = vol.flatten()

contours = grid.contour([0])  # Isosurface = 0

# %% Visualization

pv.set_plot_theme('document')

p = pv.Plotter()

p.add_mesh(contours, scalars=contours.points[:, 2], show_scalar_bar=False, interpolate_before_map=True,
           show_edges=False, smooth_shading=False, render=True)

p.show_axes_all()

p.add_floor()

p.show_grid()

p.add_title('Gyroid')

p.show(window_size=[2040, 1500])
```